# CtrlP Error detected while processing function <SNR>45_AcceptSelection..ctrlp#acceptfile..<SNR45>_openfile:

Tags: vim, ctrlp

When trying to open files in VIM with the CtrlP Plugin, I receive the following error:

```
CtrlP Error detected while processing function <SNR>45_AcceptSelection..ctrlp#acceptfile..<SNR45>_openfile:
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused if the directory to your swap files doesn't exist.  By default, vim places swap files in the same directory as the source file, so it's usually not an issue, but if you move your swap files to a different directory, vim won't create the directory if it does not exist.